# why VSPerfCmd leads to blue screen of death?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008

Whenever I am trying to run the [VSPerfCmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182403%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in my machine with [TRACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255420%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), it is crashing with blue screen of death. When I try the same with `SAMPLE` it is not crashing but if I launch any app it is crashing that time.

Am using VS 2008, installed Profiling Tool stand alone installer. I have VS 2010 also, I couldn't find this VSPerfCmd.exe since the Performance Tools folder is not there.

Comment: Because it installs a device driver.  And that's what device drivers do when they fail.  Your VS versions are getting old, don't try to use them on [Windows 8.x](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2012/12/10/the-visual-studio-profiler-on-windows-8.aspx)

Comment: @HansPassant what device driver?  I get bsod on win7 x64 also, using vs2008 and vsperfcmd.